# how can i extract information from two forms in a html page then send it to my email (using php)

Tags: php, html, forms

i have a static one page site, with two forms, that i want to extract the information of the fields of that forms then send it to my email
this is the code of the two forms:
my exact question is how can i creat a php page that can help me to handle the two forms and receive the info in my email

```
<!-- Reservation Section -->
    <section id="reservation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Reserve Your Tour</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading ">Explore in Our <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Tours Secetion</a>, Make Your Mind, Make Your Reservation.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name2" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email2" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone2" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>

                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Country *" id="country" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your country .">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Number Of People *" id="number" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter The number of people your comming with.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- second half !!-->
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of arrival *(MM/DD/YYY)" id="dateofarrival" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Arrival Date.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of departure * *(MM/DD/YYY)" id="dateofdeparture" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your Date of departure *.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                  <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" value="ToursFatima4Days" required data-validation-required-message="Please chose one tour at least">-Tours Fatima  4 Days</label>
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" value="ToursAicha5Days">-Tours Aicha 5 Days  </label>
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" value="ToursAssmae9Days">-Tours Assmae 9 Days</label>
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" value="ToursZaina5Days">-Tours Zaina 5 Days</label>
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" value="AdventuresSafaris">-Adventures Safaris</label>
                                  </div>
                                 <br><br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                <div id="success"></div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Submit Reservation</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section> <!-- end Reservation seccession -->

    <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Contact Us</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Let Us Know About Anything Going on Your Mind.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" method="post" action="mail/contact_me.php" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> novalidate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                <div id="success"></div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: no php? there are plenty of form to email tutorials

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for PHP's mail function. There's also mail scripts that you can use.
Check these out:

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/using-php-and-mysql/how-to-create-a-custom-php-contact-form

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/send-email-from-a-page/using-phpmailer-to-send-mail-through-php